# clBuild Options, passing OpenCL extensions

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I've looked around and been unable to find the solution to what I find a relatively simple OpenCL related question.

Thing is, I just started using double precision in my OpenCL kernels, as my current project requires that much precision. Furthermore, I'm trying to keep everything managed, so that all kernels have the same #DEFINES that they can use.

Then I came to the extentions. By OpenCL I'll have to include

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

How do I include this in the build-options for clBuildProgram?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the extensions supported by a device from the host calling `clGetDeviceInfo` with CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS (section 4.2 of the OpenCL 1.1 spec).  The returned string will contain 'cl_khr_fp64' if the extension is supported.

When compiling OpenCL code with `clBuildProgram`, the compiler defines 'cl_khr_fp64' if the extension is supported (section 9.1 of the OpenCL 1.1 spec).

To enable the extension in the OpenCL code, you then have to include the pragma line. You can control the use of the extension from the host code by passing an option to `clBuildProgram`, like `-D USE_FP64=1`, and then test it in the OpenCL code:

```
#if USE_FP64
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#endif
```